# Project Euler #7 Python

Tags: python, primes

I'm having trouble with my code. The question is:

**"By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13. What is the 10 001st prime number?"**

This is what it looks like:

```
div = 10001
i = 2
count = 0
prime = 0
now = []

while count < div:

    for x in range (2,i+1):
        if len(now) ==2:
            break
        elif i%x == 0:
            now.append(x)

    if len(now)==1:
        prime = i
        count += 1
    now = []
    i+=1       



print(prime)
```

I have tried div up to 1000 and it seems to work fine(for div 1000 I receive 7919). However, when I try div = 10001 I get nothing, not even errors. If someone would help me out I would really appreciate it. 
Thank you.

Comment: It's probably running correctly, just really slowly. Hint: there are more efficient ways to calculate prime numbers.

Comment: How long did you wait?  This code will take a *long* time to finish executing.

Comment: @Kevin yeah its running i just checked it it works. Any way to make it faster?

Comment: @recursive I decided to wait a little longer and I got the answer. How can I improve this code?

Comment: The [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) ought to be fast enough for the next fifty or so Project Euler questions that involve primes. (to anyone saying "telling him that spoils the learning experience": discovering the existence of obscure mathematical theories has little to do with learning how to code.)

Comment: The Sieve is one way of doing it, it's also worth noting that for checking if a number is prime you also only have to check to see if it is divisible by numbers <= it's square root.

Comment: @Hashman yeah thanks that's what I did: "for x in range (1,int(math.sqrt(i))+1):"

Answer (score 2):

```
# 7 10001st prime

import itertools


def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, n//2 + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
        else:
            continue
    return True


p = 0
for x in itertools.count(1):
    if is_prime(x):
        if p == 10001:
            print(x)
            break
        p += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
prime_list = lambda x:[i for i in xrange(2, x+1) if all([i%x for x in xrange(2, int(i**0.5+1))])][10000]
print prime_list(120000)
```

Lambda in Python defines an anonymous function and xrange is similar to range, defining a range of integer numbers. The code uses list comprehension and goes through the numbers twice up to the square root of the final number (thus i**0.5). Each number gets eliminated if it is a multiple of the number that's in the range count. You are left with a list of prime numbers in order. So, you just have to print out the number with the right index.

Comment: ... and why does that work? What does it do? How does it relate to the code the OP posted?

Comment: It gives you the solution to the euler_7 problem, the 10001st prime number (since python numbering is 0 based).

Comment: Yes, it does.  But ***why***?  What does xrange mean? or the lambda? How does this all fit together to give the answer? And that said, its not even fixing or addressing the issue the OP had with the code being asked about.  Its something *completely* different which doesn't help the OP learn anything, nor the next person.

Comment: lambda in Python defines an anonymous function and xrange is similar to range, defining a range of integer numbers. The code uses list comprehension and goes through the numbers twice up to the square root of the final number (thus i**0.5). Each number gets eliminated if it is a multiple of the number that's in the range count. You are left with a list of prime numbers in order. So, you just have to print out the number with the right index.

Comment: Could you put that in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

With just some simple modifications (and simplifications) to your code, you can compute the number you're looking for in 1/3 of a second.  First, we only check up to the square root as @Hashman suggests.  Next, we only test and divide by odd numbers, dealing with 2 as a special case up front. Finally, we toss the whole `now` array length logic and simply take advantage of Python's `break` logic:

```
limit = 10001
i = 3
count = 1
prime = 2

while count < limit:

    for x in range(3, int(i ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
        if i % x == 0:
            break
    else:  # no break
        prime = i
        count += 1

    i += 2

print(prime)
```

As before, this gives us 7919 for a limit of 1000 and it gives us 104743 for a limit of 10001.  But this still is not as fast as a *sieve*.

Answer (score -1):

```
m=0

n=None

s=1

while s<=10001:

        for i in range(1,m):

            if m%i==0:n=i

        if n==1:print(m,'is prime',s);s+=1

        m+=1
```